# Streaming OpenCV Human Detection video from python program to Django Webpage

Tags: python, html, django, opencv

Im currently developing a webpage that allows users to upload a video, run the video through opencv human detection program and display the video feed to a django webpage.

I was wondering, is this possible and if possible could you send me in the right direction as ive looked and a lot of the sources ive looked at are just for normal video streams or streaming using flask which i have no experience in

many thanks :)

Comment: Its too broad, but you can crate a URL in your URLs file of the django which will accept the video for example `POST /my_video`. Process that video and prepare a HTTP response to return back so that you can display that on your web. If your OpenCV program is taking longer time to process the video and you get your HTTP expired during processing, I would recommend using queues and store the result of each request in a DB. You submit your video and create a job in a queue and after its gets processed you simply store result into DB. You can use Redis-Queue for that. This is what I am using.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, im sorry its broad but if this helps you answer my question better i want to do what this guy does in the link provided (but in django and from an existing video not live): https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/video-streaming-with-flask#commentform